# pytorch TabularDataset: can't load a large file?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, torch

I have this training set of about 1.4 GB, but I can't load it in a TabularDataset.

```
>>> REF = data.Field(lower=True, tokenize=tokenize_char, init_token='<sos>',eos_token='<eos>')
>>> SRC = data.Field(lower=True, tokenize=tokenize_char)
>>> train = data.TabularDataset('./train.csv', format='csv', fields= [('src', SRC), ('ref', REF)])
Killed
```

For small dataset, this code works fine. I don't really understand why the process got killed, since the dataset is not enormous large. Any idea how I can load this file? thanks!

Comment: Is this "small dataset" a subset of this 1.4 GB file? Have you tried to split `train.csv` into smaller files and see when it starts to break?

Comment: thanks for the reply. small dataset is the test set, which contains about 3000 sentences, the training set contains over 4 million sentences.